# Android: How to call certain method after certain time?

Tags: java, android, timer, handler

I am a newbie to Android App Development. I want to call a certain method after certain time and I am unable to do that. The methods I have tried include the postDelayed method.

Here is the code I want to execute after 2000ms

```
private void computersTurn() {
    rollButton.setEnabled(false);
    holdButton.setEnabled(false);
    while (currentTurn=='C' && cTurn<=20 && cTotal<=100) {
        rollDice();//TO BE EXECUTED AFTER INTERVALS
    }
    hold();
    rollButton.setEnabled(true);
    holdButton.setEnabled(true);
}
```

The code for whole activity can be found here: http://pastebin.com/bzkfydpL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code to delay execution of your function:

```
private int DELAY = 1500; // Delay time in milliseconds

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
              computersTurn();
           }
         }, DELAY);
```

Comment: @lulian Thanks but UI freezes with this method.

Comment: This is an acceptable answer to your question. It does execute the code after a given delay. The reason your UI freezes is because of the work you are trying to do on the main/UI thread during computersTurn(). You need to move where that code executes to a new thread. You will of course then have to return to the main thread if you want to update any UI elements. Android guide:  http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Comment: Yeah you should use AsyncTask to do it in a different thread and don't block the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
    Handler handler  = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    computersTurn();
                }
            },2000);
```